# Is there fat that once gained is permanently there (for example: chin)?

Tags: weight-loss, body-fat, weight-gain, fat

I gained lot of weight in less than 6 months (about 10kg) because I started taking medicine which as a side effect had higher desire to eat.

Now I am losing some weight and am getting closer to weighing like before I gained those kilograms.

However I feel like the fat on the lower side of my belly and especially the fat under my chin isn't getting smaller so I was wondering if there is fat that once gained will forever be there?

I think there is some reduction (I had double chin visible at first but now it is only visible when slightly tilting my head to the ground) but it is very little and very slow compared to other parts.

I lost weight mainly because of caloric deficit and not because I exercised alot.

Comment: This question falls more under human biology than exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Fat accumulation patterns depend on sex, but within the same sex, they are really specific to each individual and many people have places where fat is really hard to lose.

First thing is that spot reduction is not really possible short of surgery.

That said, if you maintain a moderate caloric deficit for long ideally both by increasing exercise and controlling your intake it will be (eventually and mostly) gone. The key thing in my experience is to understand it may take you more than the 6 months it took you to get it, maybe even twice as long or more.

So please don't do really extreme dieting or anything out of impatience, as that will be very counterproductive. Find a routine that's sustainable for you, and stick to it.